# While Controller inside Transaction Controller doesn't get displayed even after successful run

Tags: controller, jmeter

Working on JDBC request and passing multiple values in it. Now I have used the Transaction Controller and inside that using While controller for execution of all values from source file --- ${Variable}. 
The all values are executed but the result doesn't get displayed in Transaction Controller.
When using ${__javaScript("${VALUE}" != "VALUE",)} it is executing only 3 requests.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jiDg.png)

Answer (score 0):

While Controller will execute its children given the condition resolves to `true`. You can validate the condition by placing i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) before the While Controller and ensure that the condition is met.

[image]

Also be aware that using __javaScript() function is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, consider migrating to i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) instead.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I am working on it and will try to resolve it as per your inputs. Just for now, I have used logic controller and counter to solve it and it works fine. Please share your valuable thoughts on this.

Comment: awaiting your positive response @Dmitri